# Using OAuth2 on non-REST endpoints

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization, page-controller

I have a custom module which includes a `ControllerBase`. The controller has a `content()` function that returns a `JsonResponse()`. The code for this function returns a complete list of a certain entity type.

I've tried using REST for this, but the entity structure is decently complicated and contains several field collections. By default, REST will just include the ID of a field collection as part of its presentation of this entity, so I've written a `FieldFormatter` plugin that replaces the field collection ID with a JSON object of its contents. Unfortunately, that requires significant overhead when returning an entire list of the entity type via REST, and takes 40 seconds to load. However, OAuth2 works fine with it.

Alternatively, my existing custom connector takes approximately two to three seconds to load, as it is a single sanitized SQL statement that outputs its results as a JSON. However, I only have Basic Auth working with this, attempting OAuth2 returns a 403 error. I am using the simple_oauth module.

I'm wondering if there is a way to:

- A) improve the response time on the REST endpoint to be as good as the custom controller

  or
- B) use OAuth2 with the custom controller. I've been looking for instructions on this but every OAuth2 resource I've come across so far assumes I'm using a REST endpoint.

edit to update: The REST endpoint is caching, which seems good as it's now loading much faster after the initial fetch, but (as is expected behaviour) the cache is flushed along with all other caches which is something we need to do fairly often, meaning the next person to access the endpoint will see an unusually slow response time. This isn't ideal, and I'd like to still investigate the custom controller I made, however adding `_auth: ['oauth2']` to the YAML file is not fixing the 403 error.

2nd edit to update: This is my YAML for the custom controller, which is also not working:

```
connector.modulename:
  path: '/connector/modulename'
  defaults:
    _controller: \Drupal\connector\Controller\ModuleNameConnectorController::content
  requirements:
    _permission: 'view modulename entity'
  options:
    _auth: ['simple_oauth']
```

It does not work with `_auth: ['simple_oauth']` or `_auth: ['oauth2']` (403 error), but does work with `_auth: ['basic_auth']`. I'm using Postman to connect with a fresh (~30 sec, expiry 5 min) token. The same oauth2 token works for the REST connector. The error message I'm getting in my admin logs states:

```
League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. in League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::accessDenied() (line 173 of C:\directory_to_my_site\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Exception\OAuthServerException.php).
```

and also issues a PHP warning stating that access was denied to `Guest (not verified)`.

Comment: I don't have time to dig deeper (and assuming you're using the simple_oauth module), looking at the code and [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244591/custom-authentication-provider-returns-403-for-access-true), it might be as simple as adding `_auth: ['oauth2']` to the `options` of the route for the custom controller (maybe instead of `_access` but I'm not sure)

Comment: @Clive Thank you! I was about to be really embarrassed that it was that easy, but I'm still getting a 403 error after changing the provider to oauth2 (I am using simple_oauth), clearing cache, and using a fresh access token. I will have to look into this tomorrow.

Comment: Have you tried `_auth: ['simple_oauth']`?

Comment: @Jdrupal Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it's still giving me a 403 error. I'll update my question in case something's wrong with my YAML itself.

Comment: Why do you have both permission and auth?

Comment: @Jdrupal Not all user roles have access to this entity type, so it should deny them if they are either not logged in, or logged in but don't have the correct role.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but why not just make a custom rest plugin endpoint and move your code from controller to that ?? Example https://github.com/enzolutions/entity_rest_extra/blob/master/src/Plugin/rest/resource/EntityBundlesResource.php .  ?? then implment your own cashing ?

also what is the method GET , POST ?

Comment: @TaggartJensen basically using any entity methods (such as \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage) is causing the REST endpoint to operate extremely slowly because of the amount of field collections that need to be expanded, so I need to do this with as few database queries as possible. Using GET.

Comment: then cache it like .... 

 $data = NULL;
if ($cache = \Drupal::cache()->get('something')) {
   $data = $cache->data;
 }
  else {
    $data =  (do the expensive slow stuff  here)
    \Drupal::cache()->set('something', $data);
 }

see core/core.api.php line 434 ish.

Comment: This is the most embarrassing thing I've ever posted. I was using a refresh token instead of an access token. That's why I was getting a 403 error. The code was fine all along.

Answer (score 1):

> A) improve the response time on the REST endpoint to be as good as the
>   custom controller

For the REST endpoint, you can use `$response->addCacheableDependency()` check this block for example:
https://blog.dcycle.com/blog/2018-01-24/caching-drupal-8-rest-resource/
https://spinningcode.org/2017/05/cached-json-responses-in-drupal-8/

Make sure to add cache context and cache tags, carefully.

> B) use OAuth2 with the custom controller. I've been looking for
>   instructions on this but every OAuth2 resource I've come across so far
>   assumes I'm using a REST endpoint.

Check the example from "simple_oauth_extras" sub module of "simple_oauth"
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/simple_oauth/blob/8.x-3.x/simple_oauth_extras/simple_oauth_extras.routing.yml#L22

Controller is:
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/simple_oauth/blob/8.x-3.x/simple_oauth_extras/src/Controller/DebugController.php#L39