# AccessDeniedHttpException on a route with _access: TRUE

Tags: 8, routes, authentication-authorization

In my custom module I have a few "publication" routes that do not need any kind of authentication. Months ago I learnt that I could achieve this with the following requirements in routing.yml:

```
my_module.myroute:
  [...]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

This works on my existing routes.

Now I'm trying to add a new one that parses the `Authorization` HTTP header *only for identification purposes*: the purpose is to show a custom view on *public* data, without any authentication or authorization need. So, I tried to reach my custom route adding an `Authorization` header (via a browser extension), and I get the following error:

```
Path: /CLS/it/pub/quadroxml. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: 
The used authentication method is not allowed on this route. 
in Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\AuthenticationSubscriber->onExceptionAccessDenied() 
(line 134 of [...]/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/AuthenticationSubscriber.php).
```

So, sending an `Authorization` header apparently triggers some authentication method even on routes with `_access: 'TRUE'`.

Can I disable *completely* all authentication and authorization on some routes? Alternatively, can I enable the "used authentication method" on my route, and then accept any password? (I am only interested in the user id!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @4k4 answer, I implemented a custom authentication provider, as detailed [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/authentication-api/create-a-custom-authentication-provider): the sample implementation used on that page only checks for the presence of an header, I just had to replace `X-Auth-Token` with `Authorization` to get the code to do what I need.

With a minor, but important correction: if I left `priority: 10` in the tags of the authentication service, I *still* keep on getting the same error when I send an `Authorization` header in the request. I struggled with this problem for a few hours, googling and searching; in the end my eye fell on the `priority: -10` value of a path processor service I implemented months ago, where I had left the helpful comment "Low priority acts last", so I changed the value of the priority to 1000, and suddenly I managed to get my route to work!

I don't understand exactly why this happens, since I had only my custom authentication provider in the `_auth` vector under `options`, so I don't see how another provider can get a higher priority. I think this may be a bug, I'll try to find the time to reproduce it on a clean installation and file it.

Anyone needing help on this issue should also have a look at [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244591/custom-authentication-provider-returns-403-for-access-true): it didn't help me much because the problem with priority is not mentioned, but since the problem is exactly the same, maybe other hints may be collected.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about how to accept any password. But there is a difference between the default user authentication and `basic_auth` you are probably using for this route. The first one is defined as global:

*core/modules/user/user.services.yml*

```
user.authentication.cookie:
    class: Drupal\user\Authentication\Provider\Cookie
    arguments: ['@session_configuration', '@database', '@messenger']
    tags:
      - { name: authentication_provider, provider_id: 'cookie', priority: 0, global: TRUE }
```

while the second one is not:

*core/modules/basic_auth/basic_auth.services.yml*

```
services:
  basic_auth.authentication.basic_auth:
    class: Drupal\basic_auth\Authentication\Provider\BasicAuth
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@user.auth', '@flood', '@entity_type.manager']
    tags:
      - { name: authentication_provider, provider_id: 'basic_auth', priority: 100 }
```

In this case the route needs to specify the `_auth` option. See

https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/structure-of-routes

Comment: Well, this is indeed not complete, but it put me on the right track. I understood that the authentication providers available were not suited to my needs, so I implemented a custom one. and then I added it to the `_auth` option, as I suggested. I think this may deserve a new answer, and a comment to the other question that put me on the right track...

Comment: I've hesitated to suggest a custom authentication provider, because the question topic was the route definition. But showing the two core definitions was pointing in that direction and then of course you need a priority of >100 to override both.

Comment: Yes, indeed it pointed in the right direction. I'm curious about your statement on the priority, is it possible that if I use a low priority the predefined authentication providers are still used? I ask because that's what seems to be happening...

Comment: If you have enabled HTTP Basic Authentication and you are sending an Authorization header, this module is used, unless you implement a custom authentication provider with a higher priority. The authentication happens before routing. After routing it's only checked whether the provider which won the authentication race before is appropriate for the route.

Comment: I see. That explains everything I saw. I didn't find this behaviour documented anywhere – but I may have not looked deep enough. Also, I guess that implementing a custom behaviour on an HTTP Basic Authentication is not really a common requirement, especially nowadays... Anyway, I think that _now_ this is documented, _here_ :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do pretty much anything you want when it comes to access control, by either defining a custom access check via a controller class (1) that you set directly on the specific route, or by creating your own access check service (2).

**1. Access check via controller class**

Docs: [Custom route access checking](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes/custom-route-access-checking)

`example.routing.yml`

```
example:
  [...]
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::access'
```

`ExampleController.php`

```
class ExampleController {

  public function access(AccountInterface $account) {
    // Return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultInterface here
  }

}
```

**2. Access check service**

Docs: [Advanced route access checking](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122195)

Basically, you do the same thing that provides the `_access` parameter that you already use (which is implemented by [DefaultAccessChecker](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21DefaultAccessCheck.php/class/DefaultAccessCheck/9.3.x). So you create a tagged service and set that service to be a requirement on your route. The example from the docs is very complete, so I don't copy that here.

Comment: Thank you, I already add a custom route access check in my module. I tried to add another one for this new path, but it made no difference: in the end I managed to solve my problem using a custom authentication provider, so I guess my problem was in the earlier phase of authentication rather than in the access check phase.